# Search API Views only displaying one result

Tags: 7, views, search

I've just cloned a production site into a staging environment. I copied core and contribute, cloned the repo containing custom modules and themes, cloned the database and copied the solr configuration to a new core. Bringing up the database I configured a new search server pointing to the new core, repointed the index and reindexed the site.

All my old search API Views, and all new ones I create, only show one result. However the pager can tell that there are more. Jumping to other pages works. However no content is shown. If I do a search in solr admin I get many results.

I'm at a loss for where to start looking. As far as I can see all configuration is the same in the database and in the files. Google doesn't seem to think this is a thing.

Is this likely to be a Views issue, a solr issue or a search API issue?

EDIT: I've called the URL directly as @Eugene suggested. It looks to me like only one result *is* returned by Solr. However as you can see it things that a larger number has been found.

Query string:
http://example.com:8983/solr/core2/select?fl=item_id%2Cscore&start=0&rows=10&facet=true&facet.sort=count&facet.limit=10&facet.mincount=1&facet.missing=false&facet.field=sm_field_domains%24name&facet.field=im_field_regions&facet.field=im_field_topics&facet.field=im_field_sources&facet.field=im_field_domains&f.sm_field_domains%24name.facet.limit=50&f.im_field_regions.facet.limit=50&f.im_field_regions.facet.mincount=0&f.im_field_topics.facet.limit=50&f.im_field_sources.facet.limit=50&f.im_field_domains.facet.limit=50&f.im_field_domains.facet.mincount=0&group=true&group.main=true&group.field=ss_field_source_url%3Aurl&wt=json&json.nl=map&q.alt=%28ss_type%3A%22article%22%29%20%28bs_status%3A%22true%22%29%20%28index_id%3A%22solr_local%22%29%20%28hash%3Agpsxif%29

Response

  `"response": {
    "numFound": 197180,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 2.0000253,
    "docs": [
      {
        "item_id": "1646",
        "score": 2.0000253
      }
    ]
  },
...
}`

Comment: I guess that it's search_api_views or views issue. Did you check filters in your view?

Comment: Even if I create a brand new view with no filters on the index I still get one result. If I create a normal content view I get the normal number of results.

Comment: Mhh... try to open file ...search_api_solr/includes/solr_connection.inc there is function sendRawGet(). In this function you can see $this->makeHttpRequest($url, $options); Put there a break point and execute your view. After that copy value from $url and put it into browser address field to check is solr returns only 1 result or not.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. I've updated my question. I think it shows just one result. What I should do is check the query to see if that is what views requested.

Comment: @Queenvictoria can you provide the URL that you used to generate the Solr result you pasted above?

Comment: I checked the URL and it specified 10 rows. Also if you click through the pager you get no results displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove this from your url

```
&group=true&group.main=true&group.field=ss_field_source_url
```

Comment: Yes that works well. I can't see anything in Views that is grouping on that field. I'll look through the rest of the configuration and custom modules. It's weird that this is a clone of a functioning site and that a new View with no configuration also shows the same issue.

Comment: Views aggregation isn't active?

Comment: Ok I apologise for running it circles. I wrote a custom module a year ago to do this. For some reason it doesn't have this effect on the production site. I'll look more into that. Thank you for working through the issue with me @Eugene.